# Javascript forms. making 1 entry dependant on another

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, dialog

I have a form with multiple questions like: "do you 'A'", "if not, do you have 'B'?"
rather than have all of these questions showing at the same time, which would take a lot of room, how can i use javascript to have the second form question pop up only if the answer to the first question is no? I'm using a radio buttons and checkboxes as my question input.

ALSO, im using a UI-jquery dialog box to display this form, is that going to change what I can do with the form or does that not make any difference?

Comment: You're looking for Javascript, not PHP, I updated the references and retagged for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using jquery-ui, I assume you have access to jQuery.

You can bind an onchange event to option a, and use the value of the option to dictate whether or not to show option b. Something like below:

```
$("#optionA").on("change", function () {
    if (this.value !== '') {
       $("#optionB").css('display', '');  // show the option
    }
    else {
       $("#optionB").css('display', 'none'); // hide the option
    }
});
```

The value of the form element will vary based on the type of the element (e.g. radio, checkbox, etc.), but the above code should get you in the realm of what you need.

Comment: where would i put this code? within my form? im not all that used to jquery

Comment: also, cant i say something like "if the value for #question1 equals "no", echo: question2? if i can do that i have absolutely no idea what the syntax would be

Comment: Here is a working jsFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/sGALv/

Your JavaScript would go in a <script></script> tag within the <head> section, or at the very end of your page. I wouldn't recommend echoing the second question via php, as this may result in you having to dynamically build and destroy the content if the user toggles their answer. Having it static and just changing the display is a simple way to get what you need.

Comment: You pasted the same Fiddle as mine, which is working. Did you modify and post the wrong link?